# angular unable to set value to form control

Tags: angular, form-control

Basically I'm trying to edit and update my existing data on database.
So, First as required, i'm getting data from DB for a particular Employee and set it to my EMPLOYEE property, as shown below --,

This the class property where i'm saving data after getting from DB.

```
  employee: any; //This is where the employee saved after getting from DB
```

This method is getting data from DB and it getting successfully.

```
getEmployee(id){
    var url = `http://localhost:3000/employee/get/${id}`;    
    this.crudService.getItem(url).subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.employee = data.data;     
    })
  }
```

after that i want to use and set the value to one of my Form input as default value by the Class Property EMPLOYEE. i'm using it like this(below) with FORM CONTROL, but not working --,

```
this.employeeName = new FormControl(
      this.employee.employeeName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50)]
    );
```

But it working when i'm using it to the html directly by the VALUE ATTRIBUTE as shown below --,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
 id="inputEmployeeName" 
 name="employeeName" 
 formControlName="employeeName" 
 value="{{employee.employeeName}}"
 >
```

but i'm not want this. I want to set the value to the FORM CONTROL.
How can i Do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like below code

```
this.myFormGroup.setValue({
  formControlName1: myValue1, 
  formControlName2: myValue2
});
```

Comment: it shows an error  :  `Cannot read property 'employeeName' of undefined`

Comment: i'm using like this :  `this.editEmployeeForm.setValue({
      employeeName: this.employee.employeeName
    });`

Comment: Can you create plunker or stackblitz , Where I can see your code to figure out where you are going wrong.

Comment: @SushilMandi Please check the response of getEmployee(id), and add the if condition above the setting value. It might be Async causing the issue here , Before getting result into this.employee in setValue is being triggered and hence you getting the employee undefined error.

Comment: can i create MEAN App in stackblitz ?

Comment: @SushilMandi you don't have to use MEAN app , just copy your service file , component ts file and HTML file